# How to increase my Linux partition and remove unwanted partitions in dual boot system

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning

I want to increase space on my Ubuntu partition, which I installed after allocating 50 GB free space from `/dev/sda8` partition. I also have windows installed alongside. Now, I also don't know the use of these many partitions where some of them are unallocated 1MiB partitions. How can I increase 20 GB space for my Ubuntu partition and remove all these ( if really unwanted) partitions.

[image: Screenshot of GParted]

Comment: You're using pretty much all the space there is. You do seem to have too many unused 1MB blocks (usually, you get those at the beginning and the end of the drive, for padding purposes), but losing 2MB of disk space doesn't seem a big deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those 1 Mb partitions are no real partitions at all.
They are just free space that is left over at the end of the partition before it, because the partition after it must begin at nice boundary. This is fairly common before and after a NTFS partition created by Windows and has to do with the way Windows calculates the boundaries.
In most cases (not always) you can delete such a partition and then extend the partition before it slightly so it uses that, now empty, space.
But any way, they are so small it doesn't make much difference.
**And I really recommend against it as removing them will screw up the partition numbering for most of the other partitions which will make Windows or Linux, or both unusable.**

In order to make /dev/sda11 bigger you much create room for that by shrinking and moving other partitions.
Shrink one of the big NTFS paritions first (/dev/sda8 would be easiest).
Then move sda9 (*don't delete sda9 to prevent later issues with the numbering*) and sda10 forwards so they are located right behind sda8.
Now you can extend sda11 (and move it forwards too).

You can do all of this with GPartEd, but you can't modify sda11 while your Linux install is running from that partition.
So you will have to do this using a GParted LiveCD or USB stick.
(Please note that while running from the LiveCD or stick the partitions may have different numbering. Make sure you modify the correct partition !)

**As always before you mess around with the partitions: Make sure you have a good backup!**